# Typo in word "hdfs" gives me: "java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs". Using FileSystem lib over hadoop 2.7.7

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hdfs

While using `FileSystem.get(URI.create("hdfs://localhost:9000/"), configuration)` I'm getting the error "Typo in word hdfs", when I tried to run the code gives me the IOException:

```
    java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2658)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2665)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2701)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2683)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:372)
at com.oracle.hadoop.client.Test.main(Test.java:53)
```

I already tried to use in different ways to use the call to hdfs, I'm using the libraries for hadoop 2.7.7

Here is my current code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;

public class Test {

 public static void main(String []args) {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    InputStream in = null;

    try {
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create("hdfs://localhost:9000/"), conf);
        in = fs.open(new Path(uri));
        IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeStream(in);
    }  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just added this maven dependency: `http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.7.7` 
to maven `pom.xml` and problem solved.